# Linked SQL Server Issue

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have 3 servers all running Windows Server 2016 Datacenter:

Server1 is a domain controller and has ssms installed for accessing SQL Server Instances on Server2 and Server3

Server2 & Server3 are running SQL Server Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU3)

Server2 has a linked server link to Server3

Server3 has a linked server link to Server2

If I log onto server2 and run a select query which uses the link to server3

```
Select top 5 * from [Server3].[DB3].[dbo].[TableName]
```

It runs fine and results are returned.

If I log onto server3 and run a select query which uses the link to server2

```
Select top 5 * from [Server2].[DB2].[dbo].[TableName]
```

It runs fine and results are returned.

But If I log onto Server1 and open ssms, connect to Server2 and run query

```
Select top 5 * from [Server3].[DB3].[dbo].[TableName]
```

I receive error 'Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.'

And the same happens if I log onto Server1, open ssms, connect to server3 and run query

```
Select top 5 * from [Server2].[DB2].[dbo].[TableName]
```

I am logging onto all 3 servers using the same domain credentials, but it feels to me like if im running the query from Server1, then its not passing my credentials through causing the query to be ran against the target sql instance as NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON

Comment: If you right click the linked server & script it out to a new window, do they look different?

Comment: Check out [A brief explanation and solution for the Double Hop problem](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Double+Hop/76743/)

Comment: Most likely Server1 has not registered SPN

Comment: @ScottHodgin Agree it sounds like the Double Hop problem, im quite novice to all of this and have read through the article, I will see how far I can get but will most likely come back here as I hit brick walls

Comment: @Jeffrey - You'll probably have to do some Google searches on the double hop problem to see if any of the solutions will work for you.  I don't think I can provide any additional information past the original link I commented on.

Comment: The link and the results from google talk about when SQL is running as a service user from the domain, but I am using local users for running SQL on Servers 2 & 3, if anyone has any pointers for me to make this work without changing this setup it would be greatly appreicated

Comment: Are you using the same login credentials when you: Log into Server 1 and connect to Server 2 as when you log into Server 2 and connect to server 2?  Also, what user is running the SQL Server service on each server?  I'm willing to bet @ScottHodgin has it on the nose.  It's a double hop issue.

Comment: @MguerraTorres Yes using the same login. SQL Server is running as a local user on both Servers 2 & 3, the local user is an administrator. I don't like the setup but unfortunately its one of those cases where I need to fix this problem, but things like what user the SQL Server runs as is not allowed to be changed

Comment: Can you confirm the login credentials used for each Linked Server are correct/similar as @James suggested?

Comment: @MguerraTorres Sorry im not sure what you mean?

Comment: The _quick-and-dirty_ solution is to use SQL Server logins for your linked server connections instead of using domain accounts

Comment: @ScottHodgin unfortunately that's not an option I am allowed to use

Comment: If you're running under NETWORK SERVICE, then you configure the SPN's under the computer account  (SERVER2$).  If you're running under one a managed service account, it's still possible to configure, but rather tricky.  If you're running under LOCAL SYSTEM, it's no good as you can't access network resources from LOCAL SYSTEM.

Comment: Configuring Constrained delegation for managed service accounts. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ba496d63-527e-4930-922f-6cff2539813d/help-managed-service-accounts-with-kerberos-constrained-delegation?forum=winserverDS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the classic "Double Hop" problem.  Several pieces need to be in place for this to work. For server1 (SSMS) -> server2 (SQL) -> server3 (sql)

- server2 must have a SPN
- server3 must have a SPN
- server2 must be allowed to delegate permissions to server3

A SPN (Server Principal Name) is set in Active Directory on an account and basically ties a service to that account.  e.g.  MSSQL Server on SERVER2 is running as domain\sql_server.  When you connect with Kerberos, You request a ticket from the DC to connect to "MSSQL Server on SERVER2".  The DC replies with a ticket is can only be un-encrypted by domain\sql_server.

SQL Server will attempt to self-register an SPN when it starts.  This is logged in the ERRORLOG

> The SQL Server Network Interface library successfully registered the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/MYLAPTOP:1433 ] for the SQL Server service.
>
> The SQL Server Network Interface library successfully registered the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/MYLATOP ] for the SQL Server service.
>
> SQL Server is attempting to register a Service Principal Name (SPN) for the SQL Server service. Kerberos authentication will not be possible until a SPN is registered for the SQL Server service. This is an informational message. No user action is required.

**Verify that you can connect from server1 to server2/3 using Kerberos authentication:**

1. remote into server1
2. connect using SSMS to server2
3. Run this:

> select auth_scheme from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id =
> @@spid

4. If it returns NTLM, then you are either missing the SPN on server2 or you have a duplicate SPN.  If it returns "Kerberos" then congratulations, you're partially there.
5. Repeat this test by trying to connect from server1 to server3.

Once you can successfully connect to both server2 and server3 using Kerberos, you need to ensure that the accounts that SQL is running as have permissions to delegate.  This is an active directory setting that is on the service account SQL is running as.

Comment: This is a great response for someone at my level, it took me several hours to start to understand that the issue may be SPN, when I run the query, it does tell me that im using NTLM. One of the issues I have is that the servers are running as local users, not domain users. These local users are administrators. I cant seem to find any material indicating that I can get this to work under my scenario, if you are able to help with this any further it would be great.

Comment: For Kerberos to work, the DC must know about the account that MSSQL is running as.  If SQL is running under a local SERVER\user, then the DC won't know about that local account and Kerberos can't work.  It doesn't matter whether the users are local admin or not.  If it's running under NETWORK SERVICE, then that is the SERVER$ account.  I recommend NETWORK SERVICE.